# Replace Universal app with iPad app on App Store

Tags: ipad, ios7, ios8, app-store-connect, ios-universal-app

I have an iPhone/iPad app on the App Store. New version of app must support only iPad. I did all the necessary changes and tried to upload the new build on App Store but I get an error saying that I can't upload a new build which supports fewer devices than build which is already available on the App Store.

I know what is the problem, also found some old answers which tells that's not possible, but I want to be sure 100% if there is no way to replace an universal app with iPad app on the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

I would contact App Store support to find out if there is an exception. Depending on your reasons for wanting to do this, they may be able to grant you an exception.